# Is there a flutter package that reads barcode and qrcode from phone library?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, barcode

Seems very hard to find flutter plugins that support reading from library for barcode support. Mostly QR Code are only available.

Comment: Top plugins to do this ,https://pub.dev/packages/qr_code_scanner 
but not support read  from a image , https://pub.dev/packages/scan can read image

Comment: hi @AmeerAmjed, I am looking for both barcode(code128) and qrcode supported plugins.those you shared support only qr codes.

Comment: This plugin support barcode(code128) and qrcode .

Answer (score 1):

**Use this package as a library**

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_qr_bar_scanner

These are the supported types:

```
  ALL_FORMATS,
  AZTEC,
  CODE_128,
  CODE_39,
  CODE_93,
  CODABAR,
  DATA_MATRIX,
  EAN_13,
  EAN_8,
  ITF,
  PDF417,
  QR_CODE,
  UPC_A,
  UPC_E
```

Depend on it
Run this command:

With Flutter:

```
$ flutter pub add flutter_qr_bar_scanner
```

This will add a line like this to your package's pubspec.yaml (and run an implicit `flutter pub get`):

```
dependencies:
  flutter_qr_bar_scanner: ^3.0.2
```

Alternatively, your editor might support or `flutter pub get`. Check the docs for your editor to learn more.

Import it
Now in your Dart code, you can use:

```
import 'package:flutter_qr_bar_scanner/flutter_qr_bar_scanner.dart';
```